# How to test differences in means in a population that is not normally distributed, heteroskedastic and differs in variance?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, t-test, heteroscedasticity

I want to test if the means of two populations are different from each other. 
There are 12 poulations, all with different sample size, ranging from 48.000 to 300. [Here is a 20.000 rows sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0thc8moycmfyujv/data_sample.csv?dl=0). The data is the result of quantitative content analysis.

```
str(data)
data.frame: 75627 obs. of 2 variables:
$ A: Factor w/ 12 levels "1", "2", "3" ...
$ B: num 10 98 56 72 98.3 ....

mean <- tapply(data$A, data$B, mean)
mean
1    2    3    4    5    6    7   ...
6.1  5.2  5.2  5.4  5.1. 4.8  5.3 ...

stdev <- tapply(data$A, data$B, sd)
1    2    3    4    5    6    7   ...
4.0  4.0  4.1  3.9  3.6  3.8  3.9 ...

table(data$A)
1    2    3    4    5    6     7   ...
5364  5029  5285  48700  3724  995 ...

shapiro.test(head(data$B, 5000))
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data: head(data$B, 5000)
W = 0.59736, p-value < 2.2e-16

leveneTest(data$B ~ data$A, center = median)
Levene´s Test for Homogeneity of Variance
          DF  F Value  Pr(>F)
group     10  9.9826   < 2.2e-16 ***
       77219
```

The Breusch-Pagan test gives me a value of 0.0005622, so it seems the data is heteroskedastic

**My question: how can i test under these circumstances, if a mean of one group is statistically different from another?**

The Central Limit Theorem says that I could use a t.test, but the shapiro.test indicates, that it is far from normally distributed. Furthermore the variance seem to be different from each other and heteroskedastic.

Comment: Is it a random sample?

Comment: I don't understand what you test with the Shapiro-Wilk test. The hypothesis you ultimately want to test is that means are different between groups. Why would you expect the data to be a sample from *one*  normal distribution then, which is what you test there, and why do you care if it is not? I know nothing about quantitative content analysis; what kind of distribution would you expect *for each group*?